# TravisCI with pytest and numpy.load(): File not found

Tags: travis-ci, pytest

I have the following in my `tests/conftest.py` file, used to load a numpy array as a fixture object for tests that are run by pytest:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def my_fixture():

    return np.load(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "fixture", "example.npy")
```

The file `projectname/tests/fixture/example.npy` is present.

This runs fine when I launch my tests from PyCharm, but when the tests run on TravisCI I get a file not found error, with the file path shown as missing the `tests` directory, i.e. it should be looking for the file as `/home/travis/build/username/projectname/tests/fixture/example.npy` but instead it's looking for the file as `/home/travis/build/username/projectname/fixture/example.npy`, as if it's starting from the project's main directory and not the tests subdirectory which is the assumed relative location.

The `projectname/tests` directory contains all the test files, and the *.npy fixture files are in `projectname/tests/fixture`.

Can I make a setting in the .travis.yml file to configure pytest so it knows how to find the *.npy files as I'm expecting when making the call to `numpy.load`? Or is this instead somehow related to pytest's `rootdir` setting which appears to be behaving differently on TravisCI than when I run the tests from within PyCharm?

Comment: something like `cd tests && pytest .; cd ..`? However, the code that resolves files relative to current working directory is unreliable; why don't you resolve `example.npy` to `__file__` instead? `os.path.join(os.path.basename(__file__, 'example.npy')`.

Comment: Thanks, @hoefling. Your idea about using the basename wasn't entirely correct since it gave me the full path to conftest.py, but this prompted me to look for a similar approach using `__file__`, and I am now having success using the path I get from `os.path.split(__file__)[0]`. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Oh, you're right, I meant `os.path.dirname` instead of `basename`. But you got the idea anyway ;-) glad I could help!